# Haskell. How to make my program to terminate?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I want to make an "asynchronous" reading of `stdin` for a few seconds. The way I am doing if is by forking `getContents` and writing to a [Chan](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html). After 5 seconds, I kill the thread and read the channel.

From my understading, the code below should just print whatever is in `chan` and terminate, but it keeps waiting for input and `^C` must be pressed to finish. This is the behaviour you have when doing `getContents >>= print` on its own, so I have two guesses and no clue about each:

- The thread is not killed and `getContent` keep running asking for more input
- Something weird is happening with multithreading (see considerations below)

```hs
-- OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
-- Gnome Terminal
-- ghc 9.2.5

import Control.Concurrent.Chan ( newChan, readChan, writeChan, Chan )
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay, forkIO, killThread)
import System.IO (getContents, BufferMode (..), stdin, hSetBuffering)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  chan <- newChan

  putStrLn "start"
  threadId <- forkIO $ getContents >>= writeChan chan
  threadDelay 5000000
  putStrLn "\nend"

  killThread threadId
  a <- readChan chan
  print a
```

Some considerations:

- Using `getLine` make it work only if Enter is pressed. But I'd like to just "stream" `stdin` into the channel
- `hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering` is neccessary, otherwise the programm hangs (I guess waiting for end of input?)
- Using `getContents'` cause a `thread blocked indefinitely in an MVar operation`, which up to the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Control-Concurrent-Chan.html#v:readChan) is due to the channel being empty. I guess `getContents'` actually never terminates.
- Last but most importantly, the behaviour is different depending on the compilation parameters:

  - `ghc -threaded main.hs && ./main +RTS -N2` wont print anything and will hang until `^C` is pressed (same thing with `-N1`, `-N3`, etc...)
  - `runghc main.hs` will actually print whatever has being the `stdin` during the 5 seconds (i.e. whatever is in `chan`) and then hang.

Just to clarify. Here are the ouputs:

```bash
> runghc main.hs
start
abc     # user input
end
"abc^C" # ^C is done manually, to termiante the program and the last \" is for formatting purpose

> ghc -threaded main.hs && ./main +RTS -N2
start
abc    # user input
end
^C     # ^C is done manually, to termiante the program
```

So the question is simple. How do I make my program to end?

Comment: Note that you're only writing a single thing to the channel. If Haskell were strict then the `getContents` would always get interrupted and nothing would be written to the channel. But Haskell is lazy and `getContents` is implemented with `unsafeInterleaveIO`, so I guess now the reading of the input only happens after you have read the string from the channel and started printing it.

Comment: Of course I forgot to mention lazyness as a cause... So you are suggesting `getContents` gets executed in the main thread after printing isn't it?

Comment: You need multiple writes to the channel. Perhaps for your application it's enough to make a loop like `forever (readLine >>= writeChan c)`. If you want a finer control, you might need to use something like an `MVar` to keep track of how much data is in the chan. Effectively, you need to implement a buffer of some kind, and handle the synchronization issues that come with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread `getContents >>= writeChan chan` is not an infinite loop that constantly adds content to `chan`. `getContents` creates a thunk, which is put in `chan`, and the thread terminates near instantaneously. Then in the main thread `readChan` gets that thunk, and `print a` forces it. It's the forcing of the thunk which prompts reading stdin, hence your program just blocks for more input until EOF or it gets killed.

What you want to do is to explicitly take small bits of input and write them into the channel. However, in the main thread, the channel does not give you a way to tell when it's ended. A workaround is to use an `IORef String` instead as a channel. Write to it by explicitly appending to the stored string, and `readIORef` will give you whatever content was written so far.

```
import Control.Concurrent.Chan ( newChan, readChan, writeChan, Chan )
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay, forkIO, killThread)
import Control.Monad (forever)
import Data.IORef
import System.IO (getContents, BufferMode (..), stdin, hSetBuffering)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
  buf <- newIORef []
  putStrLn "start"
  threadId <- forkIO $ forever $ do
    c <- getChar
    atomicModifyIORef' buf (\cs -> (c : cs, ()))
  threadDelay 5000000
  putStrLn "\nend"
  killThread threadId
  a <- reverse <$> readIORef buf
  print a
```

Comment: Can't you just assume that the channel has ended because you sent a `killThread`? Then I think you can just do `getChannelContents` to read out the channel.

Comment: @Noughtmare Killing the thread doesn't "close" the channel. Instead you will get an MVar exception when `getChanContents` does `readChan` on an empty and unreachable chan.